# How to make call to drupal services module to filter by custom cck field?

Tags: drupal, drupal-services

I created taxonomy called "Business Type" with terms like below

Restaurant
  Non Foodie
  Winery
  Beverage
  Corporate

I created CCK called "Company" with one field term_reference type which record above taxonomy

I want to access companies listing of taxonomy term like "Winery"

http://tasteofoc.myappdemo.com/api/node?parameters[type]=Company

This returns all companies fine.

But I need to filter to get only speicific business type.

http://tasteofoc.myappdemo.com/api/node?parameters[type]=Company&parameters[field_cat]=Beverage

I am getting error for above call.

Can you please help on how to make call correct for custom CCK fields?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This will help you. http://drupal.org/node/1354202